# Remember that guy that gave up? Neither does anybody else

Tags: quotations, rhetorical-questions

> "Remember that guy that gave up? Neither does anybody else...".

What does this quote mean? I think it has the meaning like this: "Nobody remembers the guy who gave up". Is it accurate?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. The meaning is idiomatic: "People remember only those who never gives up. If you give up, you will be forgotten. Even if you have no chances of winning, don't give up, and you will be at least remembered". It's an inspirational kind of quote, akin to "If you're going through hell, keep going" (by Churchill)

Comment: Nice quote! And welcome to ELL.SE! I'll keep in mind not to give up ever. :)

Comment: Thank you all, actually I found this quote in some inspirational music video.=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you understand it correctly. The meaning is idiomatic: "People remember only those who never gives up. If you give up, you will be forgotten. Even if you have no chances of winning, don't give up, and you will be at least remembered".

It's an inspirational kind of quote, akin to "If you're going through hell, keep going" (by Churchill), or "When you are in the public eye, it's even beautiful to die" (на миру и смерть красна, а Russian proverb). You will have the benefit of being remembered, and this thought should help you in your struggle.

The first sentence is what is called a "[rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)". The author doesn't really demand that you react: "no, I don't remember the guy. Who is he?" The interrogative sentence is used to make a point. Your reply is assumed to be "no", and then the author makes a comment to this assumed reply: "Neither does anyone else".

---

Is it accurate grammatically? Yes, but there's one minor cavil:

> Remember that guy **that** gave up?

We usually use the relative pronoun **who** when speaking of people:

> Remember that guy **who** gave up?

But this is not a rule set in stone.

Comment: Yes, I know this rule, but i wrote quote as is)

Comment: No, 'the rule' is not (set in stone). In spoken English, at least that I speak and hear, the use of *that* is not only much more frequent (I mean overwhelmingly so) it also *sounds* more natural. In writing, it's more noticeable to think, hmmm, shouldn't that be a 'who' there?

Comment: Random thought: "Horton hears a *that?* - - reference to the Dr Seuss book, "Horton hears a Who"

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way. Suppose you are working hard to achieve a goal and you gave up in the midway. This means you are a loser and no one knows about you because you have not achieved anything worthwhile. However, had you achieved your goal you would be famous and people would remember you. And when will can you achieve your goal? Only if you had not given up.
eg.: You have a goal to achieve and it is to become a top tennis player. If you had given up in the midway, you would not have been successful and people would never know you.